# Network issue on Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, lubuntu

Currently, I installed Lubuntu 20.04 on my **Thinkpad** Lenovo laptop. sometimes the networks became very slow, I command a `ping 1.1.1.1` or `ping 4.2.2.4` but it falls in a very deep delay. parallelly, I connect to my modem by my Android phone and the result of *ping* is so good, something around 100 till 170 ms, this is my last *ping*:

[image]

When I turn off and then turn on the WiFi, it became ok but after few seconds it falls into trouble again and I don't know why. sometimes like now, I don't have any problems. but sometimes it became very laggy and slow.

My Laptop specs:

```
id: jjg
description:    Notebook
product:    0578JJG
vendor: LENOVO
version:    ThinkPad Edge
serial: LRPKBVK
width:  64 bits
capabilities:   smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
configuration:  
boot    =   normal
chassis =   notebook
family  =   ThinkPad Edge
uuid    =   CCCC8701-4A31-11CB-9E75-EC6C392E6F18
```

Id bridge:

```
id: 
pci:1
description:    PCI bridge
product:    5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id:    
1c.1
bus info:   
pci@0000:00:1c.1
version:    06
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration:  
driver  =   pcieport
resources:  
  irq   :   25
  ioport    :   5000(size=4096)
  memory    :   f0500000-f05fffff
  ioport    :   c0400000(size=2097152)
```

Network:

```
id: 
network
description:    Wireless interface
product:    Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id:    
0
bus info:   
pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name:   
wlp3s0
version:    00
serial: 00:26:c7:69:44:46
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration:  
  broadcast =   yes
  driver    =   iwlwifi
  driverversion =   5.4.0-31-generic
  firmware  =   39.31.5.1 build 35138
  ip    =   192.168.1.101
  latency   =   0
  link  =   yes
  multicast =   yes
  wireless  =   IEEE 802.11
resources:  
  irq   :   33
  memory    :   f0500000-f0501fff
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include relevant information such as computer type (which Thinkpad??) and wifi driver. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en

Comment: @ldias, I add new specs. please check

Comment: @ldias, thanks for your suggestion, I leave some upvotes to your post to appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue on my dell xps with Intel centrino 1030N wifi adapter.

I've posted the solution today, try if this works for you.
[Wifi is slow and unstable on ubuntu 20.04 dual boot (DELL XPS-L502X) Please help!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243381/wifi-is-slow-and-unstable-on-ubuntu-20-04-dual-boot-dell-xps-l502x-please-help)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upvote many of your posts. really thank you. if it is possible please, describe your solution here. I know your link is ok now, but under the link please write your solution. I guess it is more readable.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it and thanks. Really glad that it worked for you. @AmerllicA