# WiFi suddenly becomes slow

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (dual boot). Since then I've noticed that my WiFi suddenly becomes slow. Actually it is always slow in Ubuntu and suddenly becomes faster. I've checked with my smartphone and even Windows 10. There the WiFi works fine. How can I fix it? [I've tried this. I found it in It's Foss website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wva0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my dell xps with Intel centrino 1030N wifi adapter.

I've posted the solution today, try if this works for you.[Wifi is slow and unstable on ubuntu 20.04 dual boot (DELL XPS-L502X)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243381/wifi-is-slow-and-unstable-on-ubuntu-20-04-dual-boot-dell-xps-l502x)

Answer (score 0):

This could just be a bug in the Linux kernel. If that's the case, you're probably stuck waiting for an update.