# Killer WiFi 6 AX1650 in Ubuntu Doesn't work at Gigabit

Tags: 20.04, iwlwifi, firmware

I installed ubuntu 20 on my xps13 9300. Even though wifi works I noticed the file copy speed to my NAS is capping out around 7MBps.

I installed killer drivers as described in https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/

That tool the NAS speed from 7MBps to around 25MBps. I get about 30MBPs on the same laptop in windows so that at least looked good enough. Problem is this change somehow stopped the laptop from being able to connect to the internet.

So I had to revert back. Something I noticed after reverting back. My device is shown as,

In Windows - Killer AX1650s (201D2W)
In Ubuntu 20 - Killer AX1650i (201NGW)

Any help to resolve this would be appriciated

[windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRBut.png)
[ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMzut.png)

Comment: anyone? Any help would be appriciated

Comment: I've just ordered the 9310 (xps 13) which has the same WiFi device, I'll do my best to verify whether it has the same issue as yours.

Comment: Update: My XPS 13 9310 does not have the same issue. Just ordered a Dell XPS 15 with the same WiFi card (sigh) and I assume the same easy compatibility will be met.

Comment: this is the only thing that helped me of all the AX1650 resources: https://askubuntu.com/a/1244430/570833

Answer (score 0):

This process helped me to fix my issue

Step 1 – Download the Latest Git and Build-Essential packages

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install -y git
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Step 2 – Download the Iwlwifi-Firmware.git repository

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
$ cd linux-firmware
$ sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
$ cd ..
```

Step 3 – Create the Backported Iwlwifi Driver for your current setup

```
$ git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
$ cd backport-iwlwifi
$ sudo make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
$ sudo make -j4
$ sudo make install
```

This command might be necessary to force your machine to use the Driver from boot:

```
$ update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot your computer and verify it’s working.

Source : https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058909/wireless/intel-wireless-products.html